# User sync'd with Mail-User contact not Mailbox using Azure AD Connect

Tags: active-directory, exchange, azure, microsoft-office-365

When using AD Connect to sync on-prem AD with Azure AD for Office 365, I've got an issue where when one user syncs they're being setup as a mail-user and thus created as a contact, not a mailbox.

There is a bit of history, as this user left and had their mail forwarded probably as a mail contact when their was a hybrid/transitional setup.  So, I'm wondering if their is something still in Active Directory that thinks this user is still a contact.

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please run IDFix and check for duplicate entries in your domain.

It can be downloaded here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36832

Please make sure it can reach your active directory and is ran with a user that has read rights to your domain.

Here are detailed instructions on how to run IDFix:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Install-and-run-the-Office-365-IdFix-tool-f4bd2439-3e41-4169-99f6-3fabdfa326ac

Answer (score 0):

Look at the local AD object and determine the following attribute's value: `RecipientTypeDetails`.  Value lookup is available on [Technet Blogs](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/johnbai/2013/09/11/o365-exchange-and-ad-how-msexchrecipientdisplaytype-and-msexchangerecipienttypedetails-relate-to-your-on-premises/).

I second @jozef's answer that you should run IDFix and check your user accounts.